# Python Pandas dataframe find missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, find, missing-data

I'm trying to find missing values and then drop off missing values. Tried looking for the data online but can't seem to find the answer.

**Extracted Dataframe:**

[image: Extracted Dataframe]

In the df, for 1981 and 1982, it should be '-', i.e. missing values. I would like to find the missing values then drop off the missing values.

**Exported Dataframe using isnull:**
[image]

I used df.isnull() but in 1981 and 1982, it's detected as 'False' which means there's data. But it should be '-', therefore considered as missing values.

I had pasted my code below. What am I missing out?

```
import pandas as pd

mydf = pd.read_excel('abc.xlsx', sep='\t')

df1 = mydf.set_index('Variables')
df = df1[0:10]
print(df)
print(df.isnull())
```

Answer (score 7):

The question has two points: finding which columns have missing values and drop those values.

To find the missing values on a dataframe `df`

```
missing = df.isnull().sum()
print(missing)
```

To drop those missing values, apart from @jezrael's consideration, if that doesn't help, I suggest you to use [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

> Drop the rows where all elements are missing.

```
df.dropna(how='all')
```

> Drop the columns where at least one element is missing.

```
df.dropna(axis='columns')
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing values are not `-`.

So for missing values use `na_values` parameter in [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) for converting `-` to missing values `NaN`s:

```
mydf = pd.read_excel('abc.xlsx', sep='\t', na_values='-')
```

---

> **na_values** : scalar, str, list-like, or dict, default None
>
> Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific per-column NA values. By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: '', '#N/A', '#N/A N/A', '#NA', '-1.#IND', '-1.#QNAN', '-NaN', '-nan', '1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', 'N/A', 'NA', 'NULL', 'NaN', 'n/a', 'nan', 'null'.