# Why does Pivot table return Int64 Type Error?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, int64

I'm trying to pivot a dataframe but it keeps returning an Int64 Error. A similar question was not actually answered - [What causes these Int64 columns to cause a TypeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67337512/what-causes-these-int64-columns-to-cause-a-typeerror)

Here's the type of my dataframe:

```
#   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------        --------------  ----- 
 0   price         30159 non-null  Int64 
 1   type          30159 non-null  object
 2   size          30155 non-null  Int64 
 3   location      30159 non-null  object
 4   neighborhood  30159 non-null  object
dtypes: Int64(2), object(3)
```

the pivot table code:

```
pfraw = pd.pivot_table(pfraw, values = 'price', index = 'neighborhood', columns = 'type')
```

and the lat bit of the error message:

```
    273     dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
    275 if not isinstance(dtype, np.dtype):
    276     # enforce our signature annotation
--> 277     raise TypeError(dtype)  # pragma: no cover
    279 converted = maybe_downcast_numeric(result, dtype, do_round)
    280 if converted is not result:

TypeError: Int64
```

I dont understand why would it return an error with Int64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's create a df similar to the one OP has

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'price': [10, 12, 18, 10, 12], 'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'size': [10, 12, 18, 10, 12], 'location': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'neighborhood': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']})
```

If one prints the df one will see that this one has `int64` and not `Int64` (as opposed to OP's). **Note:** On [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72068905/7109869) one finds the difference between the two dtypes.

```
print(df.info(verbose=True))

[Out]:

 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------        --------------  ----- 
 0   price         5 non-null      int64 
 1   type          5 non-null      object
 2   size          5 non-null      int64 
 3   location      5 non-null      object
 4   neighborhood  5 non-null      object
```

And, with an `int64` one will be able to create the pivot table with index "neighborhood", columns "type", and values "price", with the following

```
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index='neighborhood', columns='type', values='price')
```

This is the output

```
type                  A     B
neighborhood                 
A             13.333333   NaN
B                   NaN  11.0
```

However, with `Int64` the Pivot Table can generate an error.

In order to handle that, one will need convert the type to `int64`

```
df[['price', 'size']] = df[['price', 'size']].astype('int64')
```

or

```
import numpy as np

df[['price', 'size']] = df[['price', 'size']].astype(np.int64)
```

Also, most likely, OP has missing values. The fastest way to handle that is to remove the rows with missing values. In order to find and remove the missing values, [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63042180/7109869) may be of help.

For the reference, [this is a direct link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/41942e1715646894cb691a30f491a5a5a78321ff/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py#L282) to the module maybe_downcast_to_dtype that is raising the error that OP is having.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the effort but your solution still returned an error. The only difference between your solution with mine is I used pd.pivot_table(df...) while you used df.pivot_table. I noticed your types had "int64" while I got "Int64". Is there a difference?

Comment: @dataaaaaaaaa can you try `df[['price', 'size']] = df[['price', 'size']].astype(int) ` or `import numpy as np` and `df[['price', 'size']] = df[['price', 'size']].astype(np.int64)` and then try to run the Pivot Table script?

Comment: So i managed to convert ['price'] as 'int64' instead of 'Int64'. It turns out I had missing values! I removed those rows (not needed). However, the pivot table is now giving out a new error: KeyError: 'price'. Already did reset_index() but it's not working.